# htaccess need help

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

Want to make simple htaccess. 
tasks is: 
site url = siteurl.com
i want to show to users folder siteurl.com/folder, but url must look like siteurl.com only.

Comment: please rewrite your question a little better - do you mean only one user for siteurl.com, multiple users for siteurl.com ar...? this is very vague and too hard to guess the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, it sounds like you need to use 'mod_rewrite'.

Answer (score 4):

Change DocumentRoot